# Multiple Primary node in Mongodb replicaset

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Sometimes our Mongodb replicaset has multiple primary nodes!
in this case mongo-b node is our real primary and mongo-c node is not responding and just have primary role in fake.

Number of nodes in replicaset: 4 (3 normal + 1 delay node without voting).
network partition and access checked and there is no partion.
we have had this problem several times since updating the cluster from version 4.2.5 to version 4.4.5.
each time we fix the problem by cleaning datadir on fake node and restarting it.

replica conf:

```
            {                                                                                                                   [25/599]
                    "_id" : 0,                                                                                                          
                    "host" : "mongo-a:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "host" : "mongo-h:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : true,
                    "priority" : 0,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(900),
                    "votes" : 0
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 5,
                    "host" : "mongo-c:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 6,
                    "host" : "mongo-b:27017",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            }
```

rs.status() result (partial):

```
                    {                                                                                                                [1881/1930]
                    "_id" : 5,                                       
                    "name" : "mongo-c:27017",                     
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 3435,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1637525581, 2),
                            "t" : NumberLong(87)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1637525443, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(87)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-11-21T20:13:01Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-11-21T20:10:43Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-11-24T07:08:32.108Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-11-24T07:08:34.867Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(2355),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1637524307, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-11-21T19:51:47Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 23,
                    "configTerm" : 87
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 6,
                    "name" : "mongo-b:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 7995003,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1637737714, 24),
                            "t" : NumberLong(88)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-11-24T07:08:34Z"),
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1637525581, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-11-21T20:13:01Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 23,
                    "configTerm" : 88,
                    "self" : true,
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
            }
```

Comment: This should not happen. I suggest to open a case at https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/

Comment: This might have something to do with it not responding.